# How to call an Objective C class method in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

On my Objective-C header, I have the following class method declaration:

```
@interface WXMediaMessage : NSObject

    +(WXMediaMessage *) message;
```

I tried to call this method like the following:

```
var message : WXMediaMessage = WXMediaMessage.message()
```

But it doesn't work.  I have set up bridging-header.

EDIT:

If I call the method as described, it will show an error says `'message()' is unavailable: use object construction 'WXMediaMessage()'`.

If I use WXmediaMessage(), error does go away. However, **will it return the same result as [WXMediaMessage message] would if called in Objective C?**

**MYAPP_bridging_header.h**

```
#ifndef MYAPP_bridging_header_h
#define MYAPP_bridging_header_h

#import "WXApi.h"
#import "WXApiObject.h"

#endif
```

**WXApiObject.h snippet**

```
@interface WXMediaMessage : NSObject

   +(WXMediaMessage *) message;

@end
```

**WXApiObject.m**

```
(It is an external api, so I can't see the content)
```

Comment: What "doesn't work?" What actually happens?

Comment: How do you mean "doesn't work"?  Won't compile?  Compiles but crashes?  Compiles and runs fine but doesn't produce expected results?

Comment: @oasisweng I've posted a new answer which I think should **completely** explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> [I mean: BUT WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818432/how-to-call-an-objective-c-class-method-in-swift/26818569?noredirect=1#comment42207277_26818569)

That's what we're left asking.  Matt's answer is correct in that renaming the method will fix the problem, but we're still left asking why.

The answer is because Swift actually remaps convenience methods to constructors.

So while we'd have to call the method like this in Objective-C:

```
[WXMediaMessage message];
```

In Swift, we should instead be simply calling `WXMediaMessage()`.  In Objective-C, this is the equivalent to calling:

```
[[WXMediaMessage alloc] init];
```

---

It's important to note that the actual factory method doesn't get called when we use the Swift default initializer.  This will go straight to `init` without calling the factory wrapper.  But best practice would suggest that our factory method should be nothing more than `[[self alloc] init];`.  The one notable suggestion might be a singleton, but if we have a singleton factory method, we should follow the pattern Apple has set, and name our factory method with the "shared" prefix:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedMessage;
```

And the following Swift code would be perfectly valid:

```
let message = WXMediaMessage.sharedMessage()
```

But if `message` isn't a singleton, then it should be no more than `return [[self alloc] init];`, which is what we'd get with the following Swift code:

```
let message = WXMediaMessage()
```

And this is what the error message is telling us to do:

```
'message()' is unavailable: use object construction 'WXMediaMessage()'
```

The error message tells us to use the default Swift initializer rather than the Objective-C factory method.  And this makes sense.  The only reason anyone ever wanted factory methods in Objective-C was because `[[MyClass alloc] init]` looks ugly.  All of our initialization should still be done in the `init` method however... not in the factory method we create because we'd rather not look at `alloc] init]`...

---

Consider the following Objective-C class:

```
@interface FooBar : NSObject

+ (instancetype)fooBar;

- (void)test;

@end

@implementation FooBar

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initialized");
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)fooBar {
    NSLog(@"initialized with fooBar");
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

- (void)test {
    NSLog(@"Testing FooBar");
}

@end
```

Now using the following Swift code:

```
let var1 = FooBar()
var1.test()
```

We get the following output:

```
2014-11-08 10:48:30.980 FooBar[5539:279057] initialized
2014-11-08 10:48:30.981 FooBar[5539:279057] Testing FooBar
```

As we can see, the method `fooBar` is never called.  But truly, if you're building your Objective-C classes correct with good practice in mind, a class method named as such should never be any more than:

```
return [[self alloc] init];
```

And your `init` method should be handling all the set up.

What's happening becomes more obvious when we use less simply initializers and factory methods.

Consider if we add a way to initialize our class with a number:

```
@interface FooBar : NSObject

+ (instancetype)fooBarWithNumber:(int)number;
- (void)test;

@end

@implementation FooBar {
    int _number;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initialized");
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNumber:(int)number {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init with number: %i", number);
        _number = number;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)fooBarWithNumber:(int)number {
    NSLog(@"fooBar with number: %i", number);
    return [[self alloc] initWithNumber:number];
}

- (void)test {
    NSLog(@"Testing FooBar (number: %i)", _number);
}

@end
```

At this point, note that our `.h` exposes the `fooBarWithNumber:` method, but not the `initWithNumber:` method.

Now let's go back to the Swift code:

```
let var1 = FooBar(number: 3)
var1.test()
```

Swift has turned our `fooBarWithNumber:` method into an initializer: `FooBar(number:Int32)`

And here's the output:

```
2014-11-08 10:57:01.894 FooBar[5603:282864] fooBar with number: 3
2014-11-08 10:57:01.894 FooBar[5603:282864] initialized
2014-11-08 10:57:01.895 FooBar[5603:282864] init with number: 3
2014-11-08 10:57:01.895 FooBar[5603:282864] Testing FooBar (number: 3)
```

Our `fooBarWithNumber:` method is called, which calls `initWithNumber:`, which calls `init`.

---

So the answer to the question, "WHY" is because Swift translates our Objective-C initializers and factory methods into Swift style initializers.

To expand on this further, the problem isn't even just with the method name itself.  It's a combination of the method name, class name, AND return type.  Here, we've used `instancetype` as a return type.  If we use `instancetype`, or our specific class type, we run into the problem.  But however consider this:

```
@interface FooBar

+ (NSArray *)fooBar;

@end
```

And presuming some valid implementation of this class method which matches the class name, but the return type does NOT match our class.

Now the following method is *perfectly* valid Swift code:

```
let fooBarArray = FooBar.fooBar()
```

Because the return type doesn't match the class, Swift can't translate this into a class initializer, so our method is fine.

It's also worth noting that if we choose `id` as the return type of our method, as such:

```
+ (id)fooBar;
```

Swift will let us get away with it... but it will warn us that our variable is inferred to have the type 'AnyObject!' and recommends we add an explicit type, so it'd recommend this:

```
let var1: FooBar = FooBar.fooBar()
```

And it'd allow us to do that... but best practice almost certainly recommends against using `id` as your return type.  Apple just recently changed almost all of its `id` return types over to `instancetype`.

Comment: Wow, your answer is very very complete and thank you so so much for this explanation. But between two posts, I think the first one targets better at my specific problem. Where the return type is indeed the class type and Swift is indeed assuming that class method mentioned above is a convenience init method for the object. In that sense, I have to select the other post. But again, much appreciated! I have learned a lot!

Comment: My post answers your exact scenario though.  Rather than change the method name to `messager`, you should instead just to `WXMediaMessage()` in Swift.  Unless your `message` method is meant as a singleton, and if so, you should change your method name to something that more obviously marks it as so.  And for that, I'd recommend the same practice that all of the built-in Apple classes use: `sharedMessage`.  In Apple classes, a factory method beginning with "shared" always implies it's a singleton.

Comment: I added a section to my answer which restates what's in my comment to add to the completeness of my answer.

Comment: The only reason anyone ever wanted factory methods in Objective-C was because [[MyClass alloc] init] looks ugly.  <---- Also the class methods would return an autoreleased object (before ARC). Do you remember that?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is the name. Swift does not import factory constructors. It detects these by noticing that the name is the same as the end of the class name.

Change the `message` method name to something like `singletonMessage` and all will be well.

If the name is `message`, you will see this:

[image]

But if I change the name to, say, `messager`, it compiles just fine.

For an analogy, try this:

```
var thing : HeyHo = HeyHo.ho()
```

You will get the same error message.

Comment: You can downvote this but it is true. And when the OP tries it he will see that I'm right.

Comment: No, it is not. This is an unfortunate feature built in to the way Swift translates Objective-C. Try it, you will see that I'm right.

Comment: This doesnt make sense! But what you pointed out is correct! If I change the name to simply "messageR". I may call the class method again! WHY??????

Comment: @matt My new answer should more completely explain what's happening here.