# Singleton instance function missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

When I import a static framework (implemented by OC) to a swift project. I find my singleton instance function is missing.

```
@interface WANetworkEngine : NSObject

+ (WANetworkEngine *)engine;
- (NSOperation *)sendRequestWithService:(WABaseService *)service
                                success:(void (^)(NSOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                failure:(void (^)(WAError *error))failure;
- (void)cancelAllOperation;

@end
```

auto translate to swift:

```
class WANetworkEngine : NSObject {
    func sendRequestWithService(service: WABaseService!, success: ((NSOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void)!, failure: ((WAError!) -> Void)!) -> NSOperation!
    func cancelAllOperation()
}
```

Xcode7.0 beta, swift2.0 
Anybody know why the instance function is missing? How can I access the singleton?

Comment: This function is missing : " (WANetworkEngine *)engine;"

Comment: Check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818432/how-to-call-an-objective-c-class-method-in-swift

Comment: @sbarow: Good find. It is indeed a duplicate, and the only solution seems to be to *rename* the factory method, e.g. to "sharedEngine".